# Float on absolute elements

Tags: html, css

I'm building a dropdown navigation menu and when i apply `position:absolute` to second layer of `li` `Float:left` wont bother at all. If is skip `Position:absolute` it screws up first group of `li` and extends the orginal div. i have create 2 Jsfiddle links to show my problem [Fiddle with absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/QJEzB/) In this one it looks like i want exept for float left on `li` with  `span`. [Fiddle without absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/QJEzB/1/)

```
<div id="navmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><span>Market</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Market1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Market2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Market3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Market4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Sale</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span>Sale1</span></li>
        <li><span>Sale2</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


#navmenu{
display:inline-block;
background:red;
}
#navmenu ul{
list-style:none; 
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
}
#navmenu ul li{
float:left; 
display:block; 
padding:0.5em; 
cursor:pointer; 
position:relative; 
}
#navmenu ul li ul{
display:none;
}
#navmenu ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
}
#navmenu ul li ul li{
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/QJEzB/8/)**
Add `position: fixed` (to the ul) instead of `relative` or `absolute`. It will fix the issue. And `float` will not apply to `absolute` elements etc.
Let me know if you want anything else.
good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can't `float` absolute elements.  You have to position them in an absolute (fixed) location by specifying it's position relative to it's nearest positioned parent.  So positioning will be done with things like `top:0` and `left:calc(350px - 100%)`.  It will take some tweaking to get your layout to work like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a navigation menu that is just one level deep, then this code will work just fine without any need to use absolute positioning in any special way.  The key thing to remember is that list items should be positioned relatively and their ul children should be positioned absolutely.  This holds true for whether you are a building a single level or multi-level navigation menu.

Now, here's a relevant plug.  In the last chapter of my book I consider a case of multi-level navigation menu that is displayed in four different ways depending on the browser viewport space.  It's a neat case that combines positioning, flexbox, and media queries.  Right now, you should be able to get the book for free from amazon.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navmenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}

#navmenu ul ul {
    top: 100%;
    width: calc(100% * 5);
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

#navmenu ul ul > li {
    float: left;
}

#navmenu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: How is this diffrent from my fiddle with absolute?

Comment: I was under impression that you were trying to fix the alignment.  See the updated block of code to display the nested list items horizontally.  The reason float: left would not work is because absolute block was constrained by the width of its list item parent.  Increasing the width of the nested ul explicitly fixes it.  It's a quick fix although I would prefer something less explicit.